# Text retrieval from an image is not appropriate

Tags: r, image-processing, rocr

I have an image where it contains names of several resources. When I am trying to read the text from the image using R its not throwing how it is present in image. For instance J is reported as I Or JI, Xyz1 is reported as XyzL I used tesseract and magick packages but still I am facing the issue.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should ask this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r ,to get better answer.

Comment: I have posted already.I was asked to post it here and that's why i did so.I am new to this environment.So i am just going with the flow.-@masoud

Comment: Please anyone provide a solution to fix the above issue